# Password no se resetea en Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8, contraseña

Estoy tratando de resetear contraseñas en un proyecto de Laravel y todo va bien menos el reseteo de la contraseña.
Pongo el correo, envía el email, abro el enlace y me sale el formulario para poder poner la nueva contraseña, pongo la nueva contraseña y entro loggeado a la aplicación. El problema es que cuando salgo e intento loggear con la nueva contraseña no me deja pero si con la anterior, en otras palabras no cambia la contraseña. Comparto el código que creo que es el que se encarga de eso y mi modelo de base de datos.

ResetPasswordController (no lo he cambiado)

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
}
```

ResetsPassword.php (tampoco lo he cambiado)

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

trait ResetsPasswords
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->route()->parameter('token');

        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
        // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
        // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation error messages.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function validationErrorMessages()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $this->setUserPassword($user, $password);

        $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

        $user->save();

        event(new PasswordReset($user));

        $this->guard()->login($user);


    }

    /**
     * Set the user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setUserPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            return new JsonResponse(['message' => trans($response)], 200);
        }

        return redirect($this->redirectPath())
                            ->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => [trans($response)],
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

El código no lo he tocado pero el visual studio me marca como que si hubieran algunos errores, en la función ResetPassword muestro en una imagen.

[image: Error en ResetPassword]

Los métodos dicen que no están definidos y la variable $user dice esto

```
Expected type 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable'. Found 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword'.intelephense(1006)
```

A continuación muestro mi modelo de base de datos.

[image: Modelo de base de datos]

Solo he usado migraciones para la tabla de users y la de password_resets y como pueden ver mi tabla Users es personalizada.

No sé a que se deba el error en especial porque el programa no muestra ningun error, aparentemente todo funciona perfectamente pero no me resetea la contraseña.

Disculpen si pongo código en imagen pero es para que se pueda ver que dice que está mal el Visual Studio Code.

Cómo fue solicitado pongo el código del modelo User
No se si algo puede estar mal en el modelo, cualquier ayuda así sea una pista de donde está la falla sería de ayuda porque como no me dá ningun error no tengo ni idea de donde podría estar la falla.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'role',
        'name',
        'surname',
        'nick',
        'email',
        'password',
        'image',
        'idPersona',
        'estado'
    ];
    
    public function Persona(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Persona::class,'idPersona');
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Tu modelo user debe implementar la interfaz que te dice el error `Authenticatable` como lo tienes?

Comment: @Xerif ya ahorita adjunto el código del modelo user. Aunque no creo que esté algo mal ahí.